# Java string concat unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, string, concatenation

I am trying to

1. Get value from web
2. Set it in common constant file.
3. Use it in other files

**So after 1st step** 
 I am able to log it like

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("(function() { return window.localStorage.getItem('machineId') })();", new ValueCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                Log.d("Got_data_from_web_view",s);
                Log.d("Got_data_from_web_view", String.valueOf(s == null));
                Log.d("Got_data_from_web_view", String.valueOf(s== null || s.isEmpty() || s.equals("null")));
                if(s== null || s.isEmpty() || s.equals("null")){
                    new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                            new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    getMachineMultivacVersion(webView);
                                }
                            },
                            300);
                }else{
                    Log.d("subscribeTo",s);
                    Constants.setMachineId(s);
                    startIntentService();
                }
            }
        });
```

And in **Constants.setMachineId**

```
public static void setMachineId(String data){
    machineId = data;
    Log.d("Got_data_from_web_view","machine id set ".concat(data));
}
```

And output is 
`02-27 15:49:16.224 25542-25542/com... D/Got_data_from_web_view: "10001"`

**After saving it in common constant file** 
`02-27 15:49:16.224 25542-25542/com... D/Got_data_from_web_view: machine id set "10001"`

**After using it to concat**
`02-27 15:49:17.215 25542-25542/com... D/subscribeTo: VMC/"V3-beta"/"10001"/HEARTBEAT_REQUEST`

But i was expecting it as

`VMC/V3-beta/10001/HEARTBEAT_REQUEST`

I am using

```
VMC/".concat(MULTVAC_VERSION).concat("/").concat(MACHINE_ID).concat("/HEARTBEAT_REQUEST")
```

to concat that variables

I am unable to find the way out any help please.

Comment: you only post a single line and even that line is incomplete. We have no overview of what those parameters you pass are, but you expect us to know what the result is?

Comment: Could you show your code?  The line starting with VMC didn't look much like java to me,

Comment: try to String.replaceAll("\"", ""), your orginal data seens have " "

Comment: @石荒人 You are awesome. That is the right ans. I wont mind upvoting if you add it as answer.